# How do I pull changes from a branch in master to a subbranch?

Tags: git, github

So I have a branch B1 which is a branch of master. I later created branch B2 from branch B1. However, when I do git pull in B2, I'm not pulling the changes from branch B1. How do I pull changes from B1? Thank you.

Comment: you will have to merge B1 into B2 to get the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either merge or rebase the branch b1 to branch b2.

```
git checkout b2
git merge b1
```

or

```
git checkout b2
git rebase b1
```

Comment: I tried the first option with the merge, but it says already up to date. However, I know it's not the case when I compare against the github commi thistory. Maybe it's pulling from master somehow?

Comment: Try to pull first before merging or rebasing.

_git checkout b2
git pull_

similarly pull for branch b1 and then perform the merge or rebase

Comment: Than you! That worked. I checked out branch B1, did a pull, then merged it with B2.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend *avoiding* `git pull` entirely, at least (or especially) if you're just starting with Git.  All `git pull` does is run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command for you.  The problem is that this obscures what is really happening, preventing you from learning what you need to know.

What you need to know starts with what a commit really is and does, because Git is all about commits.  Git is not about files, though a commit does *hold* files; and it's not even really about branches either, though branch *names* like `b1` and `b2` help you—or at least Git—*find* commits.  But while commits hold files, and branch names hold commit hash IDs, Git is really all about the *commits*.

So, each commit:

- Holds a snapshot of all of your files.  That's a full snapshot, not changes since the previous commit.
- Holds some extra information—some *metadata*—such as your name and email address, and *why* you made the commit you made.  Most of this is just for other humans, but there's a key element in the metadata that's for Git itself, which we'll get to in a moment.
- Has a hash ID.  That hash ID is a big ugly string of letters and digits.  It *looks* random, though it's entirely not-random.  In fact, the hash ID is a cryptographic checksum of the complete contents of the commit: the files-as-snapshot, and the metadata.

The result of all this is that once made, no part of any commit can ever change.  You can take everything out of a commit, make changes to it somewhere else, and then make a new commit from the result, but if you've changed even one single bit anywhere—your name, your log message, one bit of some source file, whatever—what you get is a new and different commit.  So commit *hash IDs* are guaranteed to find one particular commit, and every Git uses the same hash algorithm, so all Gits everywhere use the same hash IDs for the same commits.

#### How branches grow, or,there is no such thing as a sub-branch

The next thing you need to know is that there is no such thing as a sub-branch.

Given that every commit has its own unique hash ID, we're still left with a problem: how do we *find* commits?  The hash IDs look random, and certainly are not in any sort of useful order.  This is where Git's internal metadata, and branch names, come in.

Every commit holds, as part of its metadata, a list of *parent commit* hash IDs.  Usually there is just one hash ID here.  That one hash ID is the (singular) parent of this commit.  This ties all commits together, one by one, backwards:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` stands for the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Commit `H` itself records the actual hash ID of earlier commit `G`, so by looking inside `H` we can find the number—the hash ID—that lets us find `G`.  Commit `G` stores the hash ID of earlier commit `F`, and so on.

We've now reduced the problem to finding commit `H`.  The way we do that is with a *branch name* like `master` or `b1`.  We store the raw hash ID of commit `H` into the *name*, giving us:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- b1
```

Each branch name holds *exactly one* commit hash ID.  If we make a second branch `b2`, we must pick one of the various existing commits, and make `b2` hold that hash ID.  Typically we might pick the *current commit*, i.e., the one with hash `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- b1, b2
```

Now we need to remember which *name* we're using.  Git uses the special name `HEAD` (in all uppercase like this) for that.  There are several ways to draw that; here, I'll just attach `HEAD` in parentheses to one of these branch names:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- b1 (HEAD), b2
```

or:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- b1, b2 (HEAD)
```

At this point, let's make a new commit, in the usual way: modify something, `git add`, and `git commit`.  Git builds the snapshot for the new commit from Git's *index*—something we won't describe properly here, but this index is why you have to run `git add` all the time–and the appropriate metadata, including a log message you must write.  This new commit gets a new, unique hash ID.  The data for the new commit is the new snapshot, and the metadata is what you said, except for the parent: that comes from what Git knows, which is that the *current commit* is `H` at this time.  So new commit `I` points back to existing commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I
```

and now Git updates *whichever branch name `HEAD` is attached to*.  If that's `b2`, the name `b2` now holds the hash ID of commit `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- b1
            \
             I   <-- b2 (HEAD)
```

Note that commits up through `H` are now on *both branches*, while commit `I` is only on `b1`.  The name `HEAD` remains attached to the current branch, but now the *current commit* is commit `I`.

#### Merging

Suppose you start with:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and then create names `b1` and `b2`, both pointing to existing commit `H`.  You then select `b1` to work on, with `git checkout b1`, and make two commits:

```
          I--J   <-- b1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, b2
```

Note that `b2` has not yet moved.  Now you run `git checkout b2` to select commit `H` again.  The snapshots you made for `I` and `J` are still there, frozen for all time, but now you're working with the snapshot from `H` again.  You can now make a couple of commits here on `b2`, giving:

```
          I--J   <-- b1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- b2 (HEAD)
```

Note that, at this point, you could `git checkout` master and make new commits there:

```
          o--o   <-- b1
         /
...--o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          o--o   <-- b2
```

We won't worry about this just yet, but note that *nothing happened to any existing commit or any other branch name*.  Each time we added *new* commits, the *current branch name* moved.  The new commits all just *added* to the existing graph of all-commits-so-far.  It's totally impossible to change any existing commit, but we never did.  All we did was add *new* commits that link back to the existing ones, and then change the *branch names*.

Let's go back to the idea of merging, though.  We didn't make any new `master` commits after all, and if we `git checkout b1`, and temporarily stop drawing in the *name* `master` (because it will get in the way), we have:

```
          I--J   <-- b1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- b2
```

We can now run `git merge b2`, or we can run `git checkout b2; git merge b1`.  Git will now do its best to *combine work*, because `git merge` is about combining work.

Now, each commit holds a *snapshot*, but combining work requires looking at *changes*.  What Git does here is to use its internal difference engine, which you can invoke yourself with `git diff`.  To make this work, Git first has to find the *best common commit:* a commit that is on *both* branches, and not too different from the latest commit on each branch.

Here, it's super-obvious which commit is the *best* common commit.  That's commit `H`.  So Git will now compare the snapshot in `H` to the snapshot in whichever commit we picked with our `git checkout`—the commit `HEAD` is attached to.  If we assume that's `b1`, the commit for this comparison is `J`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
```

This tells Git what "we" changed on `b1`, with respect to the common starting point.  Then Git diffs the other pairing:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

This tells Git what "they" changed on `b2`, with respect to the same starting point.

The merge operation now combines these changes, file by file.  If we changed line 42 of `main.py` and they didn't touch `main.py` at all, Git takes *our* change.  If they did touch `main.py` too, but not line 42, Git takes *their* change as well.  If we both touched line 42, we'd better both have changed it the *same way*.  If not, Git declares a *merge conflict* and leaves us with a mess.

Assuming there are no merge conflicts—the above is not a complete list of possible conflicts, just the obvious kind—Git will be able to combine the two sets-of-changes and apply all those changes to all the files as they appear in commit `H`.  That way, the new commit that Git is about to make has *our* changes from `J`, but also has *their* changes from `L`.

At this point, Git makes the new commit.  As usual, the new commit has a snapshot: that's the one Git built by combining changes.  As usual, the new commit has a parent; since we're on branch `b1`, this parent is `J`.  But—*not* as usual—the new commit has a *second* parent too.  Since we told Git to merge commit `L`, this second parent is `L`.

Having made the commit, Git drags our current branch name forward:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- b1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- b2
```

and this is the result of running `git merge`.

#### Git is distributed

Now, you're probably not the only person who makes commits.  Other people make commits too.  You typically start by *cloning* a repository, perhaps from GitHub, perhaps from somewhere else.  This gets you all of their *commits*.  Your Git is going to call this other Git `origin`, by default.

We already saw that in any repository, we *find* the *last* commit of some branch by its branch name.  So their Git—the one over on GitHub, or whatever—has some branch names:

```
...--o--o   <-- master
         \
          o--o--o   <-- develop
```

and so on.  When you clone their repository, you get all of their *commits*, with their unique hash IDs that stay those hash IDs.  But you don't get their *branch names*.  Those are *theirs*.  Your Git takes their names and changes them, so that you can have your own branch names.

The changes your Git makes to their branch names turn their names into your *remote-tracking names*.  These names look like `origin/master` and `origin/develop`.  These remember, in your repository, where *their* **branch** names were:

```
...--D--E   <-- origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- origin/develop
```

For the *last* step of your `git clone`, your Git creates a new branch name, pointing to the same commit as one of their branch names.  You can choose which branch this is but usually it's just `master`, so that you get:

```
...--D--E   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- origin/develop
```

If you now go making new commits, you get this:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--D--E   <-- origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- origin/develop
```

Now, suppose that *they*, whoever they are, manage to create two new commits on *their* `master`.  Your Git does not have these commits yet, but you can get them.

You run:

```
git fetch origin
```

(or just `git fetch`, which defaults to `origin`).  Your Git calls up their Git again.  They tell your Git about their branch names (and other names) and your Git discovers that, gosh, there are new commits `K-L` to get from them.  So your Git does, and then your Git updates your `origin/master` accordingly:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--D--E--K--L   <-- origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- origin/develop
```

(I've assumed here they did not add new commits to their `develop`, otherwise we'd have new commits on `origin/develop` now too.)

So, this is what `git fetch` is all about: your Git calls up some other Git, and gets *new commits* from that Git (if there are any to get) and then updates your *remote-tracking names*.  After this `git fetch` you may have new commits.  What if you want to *use* them?

#### To use their new commits after fetching, you need a second Git command

Let's say that you'd like to *merge* their work with your work, to create merge commit `M` in the usual way.  You can now run:

```
git merge origin/master
```

This will make new merge commit `M` on its own, if it can, merging your `J` with their `L`, exactly as we saw above.  It doesn't matter that commit `L` is found by a *remote-tracking* name instead of a *branch* name.  Git doesn't care about *names;* Git cares about *commits*.  So we get:

```
          I--J--M   <-- master (HEAD)
         /     /
...--D--E--K--L   <-- origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- origin/develop
```

#### This is where `git pull` comes in

The `pull` command just combines two commands into one:

- run `git fetch` to get new commits from them; then
- run a second Git command to incorporate those new commits.

The default second command is `git merge`, so `git fetch` uses the commits that just came in to run a `git merge`.  But `git pull` can run a deliberately limited kind of fetch, and doesn't just merge with *any* new commits from them.  To know what to merge, `git pull` requires that you *say* what to use here.

The confusing part is that when you name what to use on the `git pull` command, you must use *their* branch names, even though your Git is going to work with your own *remote-tracking names* in a moment.  So if you want to fetch from `origin`, then merge with what they call `b2`, you need:

```
git pull origin b2
```

This runs a limited kind of `git fetch`, then merges with whichever commit they're naming via their `b2`, that your Git names via your `origin/b2`.  The missing slash here is because the first step—the `git fetch`—needs to know *which Git to call up* (the one at `origin`) and the *second* step needs to know *which of their branch names to use*.

Both of these two steps, `git fetch` and `git merge`, can fail.  It's very unlikely for `git fetch` to fail (and `git pull` will stop if it does), but if you keep these as two separate commands, you can tell which one failed, if either one did.  Moreover—and for me, much more important—you can look to see what `git fetch` *fetched **before*** you run `git merge`.  And last, not so important once you know it, you'll realize that these are two entirely separate operations in Git: fetch *gets commits;* merge *combines work*.

It's safe to run `git fetch` any time, from any branch.  Fetch just calls up another Git and gets commits from them.  This does not touch anything you're doing right now.  It's not so safe to run `git merge` any time: that merges something into your *current branch*, and you only have one current branch at any time.  If you have lots of branches to update, you can `git fetch` and update all your remote-tracking names all at once, but then you have to, one by one, `git checkout` the branches you want updated, and `git merge` each one, with whichever *commit* you want to merge with—probably from the remote-tracking name for that branch, but because you *can* look, you can check first to see if you really do want that merge.

#### Sending commits to them

You now have commits `I-J-M` (with `M` having two parents, the first being `J` and the second being `L`) that they *don't* have.  To send them your commits, you can use `git push`, providing they give you permission.  (Note: these permissions are controlled by the hosting software, not by Git itself.)  Running:

```
git push origin master
```

has your Git call up their Git, give them commits you have that they don't, that they'll need—in this case, `I`, `J`, and `M`—and then *ask* them to set their *branch* name.  Note that you do not ask them to set a remote-tracking name.  There are no remote-tracking names in this direction!  You just ask them to set a *branch* name directly.

Sometimes, they'll accept this request.  Sometimes they might refuse, because they've set up preventive barriers—maybe on specific branch names, and again, this is controlled by the hosting software—or because they just don't allow pushes at all.  Or, they might refuse because you *didn't* merge, or didn't merge recently enough.  Suppose they *had* the above, but while you were running `git merge`, someone else added another commit.  If you run `git fetch` now, you'll get:

```
          I--J--M   <-- master (HEAD)
         /     /
...--D--E--K--L--N   <-- origin/master
         \
          F--G--H   <-- origin/develop
```

which means that *their* `master` now names commit `N`, which didn't exist a moment ago.  You might need to merge again, or maybe you want to *remove* your commit `M` entirely (which is a little tricky sometimes) and make a new merge `O` that incorporates `N` this time.

Comment: Thank you, that was very informational. I appreciate it.